# MDX query Filter Function for multiple dimensions with "OR" condition

Tags: for-loop, filter, mdx, dimensions

**I have a mdx query as below with filter condition for Product Category Name and Product Name dimensions. I need the matching record from Product Category and Product Name.**

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Inventory On Order Quantity]} ON COLUMNS
 ,
    Filter
    (
      [Product].[Product Category Name].[Product Category Name].MEMBERS
     ,
        [Product].[Product Category Name].Member_value = 'Audio'
      OR 
        [Product].[Product Category Name].Member_value = 'Cameras and camcorders'
    )
  * 
    Filter
    (
      [Product].[Product Name].[Product Name].MEMBERS
     ,
            [Product].[Product Name].Member_value
          = 'A. Datum Advanced Digital Camera M300 Azure'
        OR 
            [Product].[Product Name].Member_value
          = 'A. Datum Advanced Digital Camera M300 Black'
      OR 
          [Product].[Product Name].Member_value
        = 'A. Datum Advanced Digital Camera M300 Grey'
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Operation];
```

**It appies "AND" condition between "Product Category Name" and "Product Name" due to "*" in between.**

Can anyone help me to make it "OR" condition, I saw the below link but could not make it work.

[MDX - Filter multiple dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865118/mdx-filter-multiple-dimensions)

Comment: ok - think I understand - you would like, for example, data where Cat Name is ''Cameras and camcorders'' and then Prod Name can be _anything_. Or Prod Name is ''A. Datum Advanced Digital Camera M300 Azure'' and Cat Name is _anything_ ? Because they are the same dimension the crossjoin `*` is enforcing autoexist behaviour - this is as expected. There will be a way though - I'm having a play now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact names of your members so you will need to play around with those but I suspect you can use the `Exists` functions against a `set` of `tuples` with the same dimensionality as the cross-joined hierarchies:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Inventory On Order Quantity]} ON COLUMNS
 ,Exists
  (
    {
        [Product].[Product Category Name].[Product Category Name].MEMBERS
      * 
        [Product].[Product Name].[Product Name].MEMBERS
    }
   ,{
      (
        [Product].[Product Category Name].[Product Category Name].[Audio]
       ,[Product].[Product Name].[Product Name].[(All)]
      )
     ,(
        [Product].[Product Category Name].[Product Category Name].[Cameras and camcorders]
       ,[Product].[Product Name].[Product Name].[(All)]
      )
     ,(
        [Product].[Product Category Name].[Product Category Name].[(All)]
       ,[Product].[Product Name].[Product Name].[A. Datum Advanced Digital Camera M300 Azure]
      )
     ,(
        [Product].[Product Category Name].[Product Category Name].[(All)]
       ,[Product].[Product Name].[Product Name].[A. Datum Advanced Digital Camera M300 Black]
      )
     ,(
        [Product].[Product Category Name].[Product Category Name].[(All)]
       ,[Product].[Product Name].[Product Name].[A. Datum Advanced Digital Camera M300 Grey]
      )
    }
  ) ON 1
FROM [Operation];
```

Here is an AdvWks script that gets all customer with their respective gender and marital status:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer]*
    [Customer].[Gender].[Gender]*
    [Customer].[Marital Status].[Marital Status] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Then to get hold of Male OR Married we do this:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,Exists
  (
      [Customer].[Customer].[Customer]*
      [Customer].[Gender].[Gender]*
      [Customer].[Marital Status].[Marital Status]
   ,{
      (
        [Customer].[Customer].[(All)]
       ,[Customer].[Gender].&[M]
       ,[Customer].[Marital Status].[(All)]
      )
     ,(
        [Customer].[Customer].[(All)]
       ,[Customer].[Gender].[(All)]
       ,[Customer].[Marital Status].&[M]
      )
    }
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```